# How to connect Redmi 3s prime to ubuntu?

Tags: mtp

When I connect my phone using usb to ubuntu, it does not shows in devices, I want to access the phone file system using my laptop.

Comment: Are you using USB or Bluetooth connection?

Comment: I am using usb, to connect to the pc     @AlanDiggs

Answer (score 1):

When you connect your phone to the computer (with USB), ensure that your phone is using the File Transfer method of connecting. When you connect your phone, a notification should appear saying what connection you *are* using and to tap to change what connection it uses. You should then be able to access your phone's filesystem via Ubuntu. (Looks something like this)
[image: Here ya go]

[image: Again]

Comment: In my case it comes as
Charging only
Transfer Files (MTP)
Transfer Photos (PTP)

I select the second option but still it does not show in my system devies.

Comment: Have you tried using another cable?

Comment: yes, just tried, but nothing changed.